# Repository does not update with saved changes by UnitOfWorks

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, repository, unit-of-work, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate with EF Core 2.1 "code-first".

I have a function where I pass a parameter of type Split. In this function I will first check if this Split exists in the database with:

```
_liveEventRaceSplitRepository.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == split.Id)
```

If null, then insert, else check whether it needs to update and if so, update.
On the first call there is no problems. The Split does not exists in the database so I insert it with:

```
_liveEventRaceSplitRepository.Insert(Split)
```

In the next call to this function the exact same Split is sent as a parameter.  The problem is that my `_liveEventRaceSplitRepository` does not know that I just earlier inserted the same Split so when I call

```
_liveEventRaceSplitRepository.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id)
```

it still returns null.

How do I update repositories after inserting/updates/deletes?

I have tried to use `_unitOfWorkManager.SaveChanges()` after inserting my Split but it does not make any difference.

I have tried to put `[UnitOfWork(isTransaction: false)]` above the function/method.

I have tried to create a manual scope for unitOfwork by putting a using `(var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin()) { }` around my function.

Nothing of what I tried have made any difference.

```
LiveEventRaceSplit splitControl = _liveEventRaceSplitRepository.FirstOrDefault(sp => sp.Id == split.Id);
if (splitControl == null)
{
   _liveEventRaceSplitRepository.Insert(new LiveEventRaceSplit(raceId, split.Id, split.Name));
}
else if (splitControl.Name != s.Name) 
{
   splitControl.Map(s.Name);
   _liveEventRaceSplitRepository.Update(splitControl);
}     

_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
```

I don't know what's the best way to this, but how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you checked if your database contains the inserted row? What is your implementation of _unitOfWorkManager? Have you checked if Insert or Update is actually hit?
What is the type of Id in split?

Comment: @winters0: Yes, I can see that it is inserted in the database on my first `Insert`, but when I get the error on the second try, everything is rolled back and there is nothing. I have not done anything extra with my `unitOfWorkManager`. I have this `IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager` parameter in my constructor and I set my `private IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager` in the same constructor.  My Id in Split is just a regular `integer`. I have not checked if Insert or Update is actually hit, but since it is in the database after the first try I guess that is the case.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: @AmitJoshi, the unitOfWorkManager is supposed to commit automatically when the scope is completed.

Comment: @JörgenGranefelt in abpboilerplate or ANZ if we are using repository pattern to get an entity record to update only one property in UOW method then - should it automatically update the property in db once UOW method finishes/commits? Bcz r8 now getting list collection from db using repo to update one property & then calling update method like:

`List<OnlineOrder> ordersToClose = _onlineOrderRepository.GetAll().where(...).ToList();
// Foreach loop to update status property.
ordersToClose.ForEach(x => _onlineOrderRepository.Update(x));`

Is there any better approach to achieve this? Thnx

Answer (score 2):

OK. I think I found a workaround. I do not think that this is the way that would be needed to do but it works. I would thought that the repository would handle it all. Anyway, if I import the `using Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories;` I am able to reach the dbContext for my repository. So, after my Insert I call: `_liveEventRaceSplitRepository.GetDbContext().SaveChanges();` and after I have done this the inserted item could be found with `_liveEventRaceSplitRepository.FirstOrDefault(...);`.